# replace words to all files in the same directory?

Tags: perl, replace

is there a way with perl to change al the instances of the tags

`<english>` into `<voice required="name = VW Julie">`

`<español>`  into `<voice required="name = IVONA 2 Penélope">`

for all the documents in the same directory.

this is for textaloud, so the computer changes to other voice when the language changes

i can do it with grep, but it is boring always setting up. would be better if i only double click on the script.
but i don't know how to do it, any help is good. thanks

Comment: `i can do it with grep` -- Please enlighten us on how you manipulate a file using `grep`.

Comment: Hint: There exists an operator `s` that might come in handy.  You might also want to RTFM, i.e. [Read The Fantastic Manual](http://perldoc.perl.org)

Comment: i am an ignorant in computers my friend, but using powergrep i select the folder, (.*)(<english>)(.*)  replace for: \1<voice required="name = VW Julie">\3  , did you think i was trying to show off?

Comment: Sounds like powergrep is more like an interactive `sed`, not like `grep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work on windows,

`script.pl`

```
use utf8;
BEGIN { @ARGV = glob("@ARGV\\*"); }
s/<english>/<voice required="name = VW Julie">/g;
s/<español>/<voice required="name = IVONA 2 Penélope">/g;
```

---

```
perl -i~ -p script.pl C:\Path\to\files
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
$ cd /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY
$ perl -i -pe -Mutf8 's/<english>/<voice required="name = VW Julie">/g' *
$ perl -i -pe -Mutf8 's/<español>/<voice required="name = IVONA 2 Penélope">/g' *
```

Comment: Yes, and so what ? You have to run the command in a command terminal, with the full path of perl if it's not enabled in PATH by default, something like : `C:/Program\ Files/Active\ Perl/bin/perl -i -pe -Mutf8 's/<español>/<voice required="name = IVONA 2 Penélope">/g' *`

Answer (score 0):

Ths following Unix shell command should do it:

```
perl -Mutf8 -pie 's/\<english\>/<voice required="name = VW Julie">/g; s/\<español\>/<voice required="name = IVONA 2 Penélope">/g' DIRECTORY/*
```

The `-e` option tells perl to run the commands in the next argument. `-p` tells it to run the commands in a loop for each input line, printing `$_` after the command. And the `-i` option tells it to replace the input files with the output.

I assume this will also work from the Windows command prompt, but I've never used Perl on Windows.

Comment: i saved what you wrote in a .pl document , i place it on the same folder with other documents, and i doubled click on the pl file. but did not work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It's a shell command, not a perl script. The perl is in the argument.

Comment: i don't understand what is a shell command, but i guess i something about ms-dos , or i don't know, i thought it would be easier with perl. but thanks for the time.